# Variable++ not increasing variable size

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a busy writing a program that has a label that says "Month" on form load and when the user selects a row in a gridView the label the text changes to "March" and then there is a button that when clicked should increase a variable by 1 and changing the text to the next month which should be "April".

Here is my coding :

```
int selected, month;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void dgvBudget_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMonth.Text = "March :";
        month = 0;

        selected = dgvBudget.SelectedIndex;
        txtGLType.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[1].Text;
        txtYear.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[2].Text;
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        month++;

        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                lblMonth.Text = "April :";
                break;

            case 2:
                lblMonth.Text = "May :";
                break;

            case 3:
                lblMonth.Text = "June :";
                break;

            case 4:
                lblMonth.Text = "July :";
                break;

            case 5:
                lblMonth.Text = "Augustus :";
                break;

            case 6:
                lblMonth.Text = "September :";
                break;

            case 7:
                lblMonth.Text = "October :";
                break;

            case 8:
                lblMonth.Text = "November :";
                break;

            case 9:
                lblMonth.Text = "December :";
                break;

            case 10:
                lblMonth.Text = "January :";
                break;

            case 11:
                lblMonth.Text = "February :";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I run the program the label correctly changes to "March" and when I press the button the variable increases changing the text to "April" but when I click it any more times "month" stays the same value and the label's text stays on "April"

I just need help understanding why my variable wont increase any further.
Thank you.

Comment: Month value will always be reverted to zero because this line `month = 0;`. Move it to static variable or perhaps sessions to keep the month value.

Comment: For momth names, you may use `int month = 12;
    var dfi =new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    var mname = dfi.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);`

Comment: @Cuppyzh The month will only be reverted to 0 if they choose a new row.

Comment: Did you thing about using [Enumeration types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP Webforms are as HTTP demands stateless. That means with each new request, the month variable is reset. To mitigate this, you need to save the user's selection somewhere. ASP Webforms use either hidden fields or viewstates for this purpose. Both hold the variable you want to save at the clientside and the client sends them to the server with each request, just as he would any normal input field.

```cs
protected int Month
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["month"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["month"] = 3;
        }
        return (int)ViewState["month"];
    }
    set
    {
        // valid range for DateTime-Month is [1..12]
        if (value > 12) // check valid range
        {
            value = value % 12;
        }
        else if (value < 1)
        {
            value = 3;  // set default march
        }
        ViewState["month"] = value;
        lblMonth.Text = new DateTime(year: 1970, month: value, day: 1).ToString("MMMM") + " :";
    }
}

// ...

protected void dgvBudget_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Month = 3; // Reset to march

        selected = dgvBudget.SelectedIndex;
        txtGLType.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[1].Text;
        txtYear.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[2].Text;
    }

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Month++;
    }
```

alternatively to setting the label every time you update the property, you can update the label in the pre_render handler with the value of the property.

Answer (score 2):

Change the month variable initialization

```
int selected;
int month = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void dgvBudget_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMonth.Text = "March :";

        selected = dgvBudget.SelectedIndex;
        txtGLType.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[1].Text;
        txtYear.Text = dgvBudget.Rows[selected].Cells[2].Text;
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        month++;

        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                lblMonth.Text = "April :";
                break;

            case 2:
                lblMonth.Text = "May :";
                break;

            case 3:
                lblMonth.Text = "June :";
                break;

            case 4:
                lblMonth.Text = "July :";
                break;

            case 5:
                lblMonth.Text = "Augustus :";
                break;

            case 6:
                lblMonth.Text = "September :";
                break;

            case 7:
                lblMonth.Text = "October :";
                break;

            case 8:
                lblMonth.Text = "November :";
                break;

            case 9:
                lblMonth.Text = "December :";
                break;

            case 10:
                lblMonth.Text = "January :";
                break;

            case 11:
                lblMonth.Text = "February :";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The initialization needs to be at SelectedIndexChanges because everytime the user chooses a new row it should start at March again and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Fields in ASP.NET classes *are not preserved* across requests. Every time a request comes, you get a fresh class, with the same default value of zero for `month`.

One idiomatic way to solve this would be to make the month an *argument* - e.g. in a query string. Changing the month would be a redirect to a new URL with the next month value.

If you want to stay close to ASP.NET WebForms design (rather than modern web development practices), you can also use `ViewState`. This preserves the state you need in the browser, and it's sent as part of POST requests. Ideally, you should use a property to access the `ViewState`.

In general, while ASP.NET tries to hide the differences as much as possible, web applications are very different from desktop applications. You probably want to start with some introduction into how web applications are designed and implemented, possibly with a newer technology than WebForms (just make sure you're choosing based on the actual usefulness of any given framework for your use case).

Comment: A redirect is a bit much, especially if UpdatePanels are or should be used in the future. ASP webforms can use a thing called viewstate to save things like that between requests. I recommend using a Property to encapsulate the viewstate

Comment: @trickster625 perhaps `dgvBudget_SelectedIndexChanged` is called and resets your month?